# Vue 3 - "This relative module was not found" for png with spaces in the filename

Tags: vue.js

### Summary

After adding an image to my assets folder named `foo - compressed.png` and modifying a component to include it as follows:

```
...
<img src="../../assets/bar-compressed.png" />
<img src="../../assets/foo - compressed.png" />
...
```

... I started getting this error when trying to build (prod) or serve (dev):

```
This relative module was not found:

* ../../assets/foo%20-%20compressed.png in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/templateLoader.js??ref--7!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--1-1!./src/features/landing/MyComponent.vue?vue&type=template&id=100c0404
```

### Notes

- Other images still work in the assets folder.
- This image is certainly present in the assets folder.

Why does one image work and the other leads to this compilation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spaces in the filename were the problem.

Changing the filename from `foo - compressed.png` to `foo-compressed.png` fixed the issue.

Is this a Vue bug? Or expected behavior?

Comment: I think, nobody use web file names with spaces. Bad practice.

Comment: Definitely not a Vue bug but a bad naming. Use safe names for your files (differences between OSes are quite big sometimes).